# The simplest way to use C2DM?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

It has been a couple of weeks and I am having so much trouble making C2DM work. I've read a million guides and watched video tutorials but have had no luck. I just need a way to communicate with my server and my phone in the simplest way. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're still interested in trying C2DM, try installing the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/) and use it to generate the Android / App Engine sample project.  It should be able to generate a skeleton project that is able to communicate between AppEngine and a basic Android application.  You could verify that the sample works and use it as a basis to debug your custom application.

There was also a related AppEngine + Android [session](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-app-engine-a-developer-s-dream-combination.html) at Google I/O this year.

Comment: To add to the links, http://urbanairship.com/ claims to offer an easy solution to push notifications. Note: I do not have any personal experience with this site and am not affiliated.

Comment: Would I have to use App Engine? I heard it costs if I want to publish my app.

Comment: You can run the AppEngine project locally.  That may not be appropriate for production, but I was merely suggesting it as a way to quickly get access to a working sample.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get push into your app is to use a third party push provider like [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com) or [Xtify](http://xtify.com). Instead of writing the code to interface with google directly you integrate the third party SDK into your app and they handle the messy stuff.

Additionally, you don't have to worry about scaling if your app gets (or already is) big. And going cross-platform (iOS, Blackberry) is that much easier.